# Redux saga how to stop action from further propagating

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, saga, propagation

I'm new to Redux Saga. I want to stop an action from further propagating. I am implementing row-level auto-saving mechanism. I use saga to detect row switch action, and then submit row changes and insert current row change action. codes like this:

```
// action-types.js
export const 
    SWITCH_ROW='SW_ROW',
    CHANGE_CUR_ROW='CHG_CUR_ROW';

// actions.js
import {SWITCH_ROW,CHANGE_CUR_ROW} from './action-types'
export const switchRow=(oldRow,newRow)=>({type:SWITCH_ROW,oldRow,newRow})
export const changeRow=(row)=>({type:CHANGE_CUR_ROW,row})

// component.js
class MyComponent extends Component{
    switchRow=(row)=>{
        var oldRow=this.props.curRow;
        this.props.dispatc(switchRow(oldRow,row));
    }
    render(){
        ...
        {/* click on row */}
        <div onClick={()=>this.switchRow(row)}>...</div>
        ...
    }
}

// sagas.js
import {SWITCH_ROW} from './action-types'
import {changeRow} from './actions'
function* switchRow({oldRow,newRow}){
    // Here I want to stop propagating SWITCH_ROW action further
    // because this action is only designed to give saga a intervention 
    // point but not to be handled in reducer. I want a statement like 
    // below:    
    // stopPropogate();
    if(oldRow && oldRow.modified===true){
        yield call(svc.submit, oldRow);
    }
    yield put(changeRow(newRow))
}

export default function*(){
    yield takeEvery(SWITCH_ROW,switchRow)
}
```

I know I can just ignore the SWITCH_ROW action in reducer. But, I think it's better if there is as least round trip as possible in program. Any suggests?

Comment: u can use throw at any level. And also u need a code to catch these kind of exceptions

Comment: If u want i can share the code to catch these kind of exceptions in redux-saga environment.

Comment: As I read more materials about Redux middle-ware,  I think throw is also not good enough. I tweaked my codes and now use a middle-ware to swallow special actions for saga. See in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After more reading about Redux middle-ware, I think it's better to use a middle-ware to approach this goal.

At first, I renamed all type names of special actions for saga making them all starting with SAGA_. And then I use a Redux middle-ware to identify them and swallow them, and then those special actions can't reach reducer any more. Here is the codes:

```
// glutton.js
const glutton = () => next => action => {
    if (!action.type.startsWith('SAGA_')) return next(action);
}  

// store.js
...
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleWare, glutton, logger));
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you are in a file which is not redux component, i mean you don't have access to dispatch , so i think throwing an error would be nice, and here is the code to catch the exception anywhere:

```
export default function autoRestart(generator) {
    return function* autoRestarting(...args) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                yield call(generator, ...args);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                yield put({ type: ReduxStates.Error });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

all your sagas, need to implement this base function.